# Read a file in a macOS Command Line Tool project

Tags: swift, xcode, bundle, command-line-tool

I've added a few JSON files to my macOS Command Line Tool project, but I can't seem to find them the usual way.

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Data", ofType: "json")
{
    if let contents = try? String(contentsOfFile: path)
    {
        print (contents)
    }
    else { print("Could not load contents of file") }
}
else { print("Could not find path") }
```

This code works absolutely fine when used in a View based application, but always prints "Could not find path" in the command line tool.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

P.S: Fully aware that I should be using `guard` statements for this, but the code isn't in a function, just faffing about in main.swift till I figure this out.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no app bundle for a command-line tool. Just a binary.

You need to put the JSON file in a known location (current directory?) and construct the path yourself

Comment: Thanks! is there any nice way to get the path to a file relative to the current .xcodeproj file? (trying to include the files in a git repo)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31480186/get-path-to-swift-script-from-within-script

Answer (score 25):

You can create a separate bundle, place the files there, and then load them without having to worry about their individual URLs.

Let's do it:

1. In Xcode, click on **File --> New --> Target...**
2. Click on the **macOS** tab at the top
3. Scroll down to the **Framework & Library**, select **Bundle**, click Next. Give a name to the new bundle (let's say `JSONMocks`).
4. Add files to this bundle. Add the file to Xcode, then make sure that the bundle is ticked in its **target membership** section:

   [image: target membership for file in bundle]
5. Add the bundle to your target. In the target's Build Phases, open the **Copy Files** phase and click the `+` button. Select the bundle and click **Add**:

   [image]
6. Programmatically access the contents of your bundle thus:

```swift
let currentDirectoryURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: FileManager.default.currentDirectoryPath)
let bundleURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "JSONMocks.bundle", relativeTo: currentDirectoryURL)
let bundle = Bundle(url: bundleURL)
let jsonFileURL = bundle!.url(forResource: jsonFileName, withExtension: "json")!
```