# "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" despite being in correct bundle and build phase

Tags: json, swift, file

I'm trying to read `*.json` into a `struct`.

However I'm encountering `nil` when reading the file.

```
struct GraphJson : Codable {
    var graph: [[Int32]]
    var paths: [[Int32]]
    var previous: [[Int32]]
}

func readJsonFromFile(_ filename: String) -> GraphJson? {
        
        let path = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: "json")
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: path!) // Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
            let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
            return try jsonDecoder.decode(GraphJson.self, from: data)
            } catch {
                fatalError("Unable to load \"\(filename)\" from main bundle:\n\(error)")
            }
}

let graphData = readJsonFromFile("graph")!.graph
```

graph.json

```
{
    "graph":    [[0, 6, -1, 1, -1], [6, 0, 5, 2, 2], [-1, 5, 0, -1, 5], [1, 2, -1, 0, 1], [-1, 2, 5, 1, 0]],
    "paths":    [[0, 3, 7, 1, 2], [3, 0, 5, 2, 2], [7, 5, 0, 6, 5], [1, 2, 6, 0, 1], [2, 2, 5, 1, 0]],
    "previous":    [[0, 3, 4, 0, 3], [3, 1, 1, 1, 1], [3, 2, 2, 4, 2], [3, 3, 4, 3, 3], [3, 4, 4, 4, 4]]
}
```

To the best of my understanding, this should work. My file has the correct target membership and is listed the build phase under `Copy Bundle Resources`.

I found [multiple posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41775563/bundle-main-pathforresourceoftypeindirectory-returns-nil) discussing this issue, and so far have not found a solution to the problem.

[image]

Comment: You may find this useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43826866/read-a-file-in-a-macos-command-line-tool-project

Comment: Adding bundles to command line applications makes them fail when compiling. Reading a file from a path in a command line application seems kind of difficult.